# Win8 Metro: Collect debug and diagnostics information

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

We are planning to develop a metro app and wanted to find out what kind of support/programming model is available in Windows8 RT to collect debug/diagnostic log data. **This should quickly help/diagnose app errors in the field.**

Can we log debug data as we do traditionally in Windows apps and ask user to send the log file when encountering an error ?

For Ex. If the app misbehaves when loaded on the QA/end user machines, we can request QA/end user to attach the log files with the issue.

Comment: Asking the user to send the log files isn't a good idea. You would probably wan't to implement something that caches all the exceptions of the day. And at the end of the day (or week or month) you send the log data to a service or so.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, sorry that i didn't notice for long. we would only need the log files when a user reports a problem, most likely a call to care. And hence we were thinking that that we will implement a sharing contract or just use the apis, to take care of the stitaution

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to collect any data, windows store is doing that for you. In windows store app [Dashboard](https://appdev.microsoft.com/StorePortals/en-US/Home/Index), under quality you have reports about chrashes and app unresponsive states, these are *.cab files with debug informations.

You can open this file (*.dmp) with Visual Studio, here are the details :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj933262.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this MSDN sample : [Logging Sample for Windows Store Apps (ETW Logging in WinRT)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Logging-Sample-for-Windows-0b9dffd7) ?